# Nginx Error logs: [error] open() "/etc/nginx/html/status/" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, log-files

I am running an Ubuntu based LEMP server with the Nginx's google pagespeed, fastcgi, and modsecurity modules active. I am going through my Nginx error logs, and cannot figure out what these errors mean, what to attribute them to, and how to fix them. It seems as if something is looking for a file inside of invalid directories, and I don't know why. If someone could please take a look at my Nginx logs located at `/var/log/nginx/error.log`, and let me know what is going on, why, and how to solve it, it would be greatly appreciated! Please let me know if you have any ideas!

```
cat /var/log/nginx/error.log
2022/02/27 00:23:32 [error] 396723#502023: [ngx_pagespeed 1.15.0.0-8811] PageSpeed Serf fetch failure rate extremely high; only 9 of 28 recent fetches fully successful; is fetching working?
2022/02/27 00:58:49 [error] 396723#396723: *94537 open() "/etc/nginx/html/us" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /us HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2022/02/27 00:58:49 [error] 396723#396723: *94538 open() "/etc/nginx/html/us" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /us HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2022/02/27 00:58:50 [error] 396723#396723: *94539 open() "/etc/nginx/html/status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /status?full&json HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2022/02/27 00:58:50 [error] 396723#396723: *94540 open() "/etc/nginx/html/status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /status?full&json HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2022/02/27 00:58:52 [error] 396723#396723: *94541 open() "/etc/nginx/html/server-status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2022/02/27 00:58:52 [error] 396723#396723: *94542 open() "/etc/nginx/html/server-status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2022/02/27 00:58:53 [error] 396723#396723: *94543 open() "/etc/nginx/html/stub_status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /stub_status HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2022/02/27 00:58:53 [error] 396723#396723: *94544 open() "/etc/nginx/html/stub_status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /stub_status HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2022/02/27 00:58:53 [error] 396723#396723: *94545 open() "/etc/nginx/html/status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /status HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2022/02/27 00:58:53 [error] 396723#396723: *94546 open() "/etc/nginx/html/status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /status HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2022/02/27 00:58:53 [error] 396723#396723: *94547 open() "/etc/nginx/html/status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /status?full&json HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2022/02/27 00:58:53 [error] 396723#396723: *94548 open() "/etc/nginx/html/status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /status?full&json HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2022/02/27 00:59:10 [error] 396723#396723: *94549 open() "/etc/nginx/html/admin/api.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /admin/api.php?version HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2022/02/27 00:59:10 [error] 396721#396721: *94550 open() "/etc/nginx/html/admin/api.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /admin/api.php?version HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2022/02/27 00:59:10 [error] 396721#396721: *94551 open() "/etc/nginx/html/server-status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2022/02/27 00:59:10 [error] 396721#396721: *94552 open() "/etc/nginx/html/server-status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2022/02/27 00:59:10 [error] 396721#396721: *94553 open() "/etc/nginx/html/basic_status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /basic_status HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2022/02/27 00:59:10 [error] 396721#396721: *94554 open() "/etc/nginx/html/stub_status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /stub_status HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2022/02/27 00:59:10 [error] 396721#396721: *94555 open() "/etc/nginx/html/stub_status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /stub_status HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2022/02/27 00:59:10 [error] 396721#396721: *94556 open() "/etc/nginx/html/status/format/json" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /status/format/json HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2022/02/27 00:59:10 [error] 396721#396721: *94557 open() "/etc/nginx/html/server-status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /server-status?format=plain HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2022/02/27 00:59:11 [error] 396722#396722: *94558 open() "/etc/nginx/html/server-status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /server-status?format=plain HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2022/02/27 00:59:11 [error] 396721#396721: *94559 open() "/etc/nginx/html/server-status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
2022/02/27 00:59:11 [error] 396722#396722: *94560 open() "/etc/nginx/html/server-status" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /server-status?auto HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
2022/02/27 02:48:21 [error] 396721#474341: [ngx_pagespeed 1.15.0.0-8811] PageSpeed Serf fetch failure rate extremely high; only 3 of 8 recent fetches fully successful; is fetching working?
```

Comment: Don't you think you should share the conf files you are using?

Comment: ahh yes, I can do that. Check back a little later today and i will update

Comment: I cannot help much, except give you a hint. I have a similar problem. Probably the same. When I set an `auth_request` to a URI, I get the same error as you. The weird thing is, that it always tries to open "/etc/nginx/htmlmyuri". So, to be clear, it tries to open the URI, but prepends "/etc/nginx/html" to it. I have no idea, why it would do that. From your example, I can see that you are trying to access `/server-status`, so it changes it to "/etc/nginx/html/server-status". Same with: `/status` -> "/etc/nginx/html/status".

Comment: Okay, got it. You need to set a relative URI path, to a location. So, if you have a location leading to `/status`, then this location needs to exist in your configuration. If it does not exist, it complains that it cannot redirect you there, as it cannot open (find) that sub-page.